# How to position images in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, position

I'm not sure how to describe exactly what I am asking, basically I need to align the image to the left however in from the left by 6px (line 38, margin: 10px 10px 10px 6px).

Code is as follows:

```css
.rounded {
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#95b7fd;
 border-radius:100px;
 z-index:0;
}

.rounded-input {
 margin-top:5px;
 width:90px;
 height:90px;
 border-radius:100px;
 border:0;
 margin-left:-80px;
 font-weight:700;
 background-color:#fff;
}

.rounded-box {
 width:98.4%;
 height:90px;
 border-radius:100px;
 border:0;
 background-color:#3574f9;
 opacity:1;
 text-align:center;
 color:#FFF;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

.icon {
 height:80px;
 width:auto;
 position:absolute;
 border-radius:100px;
 margin:10px 10px 10px 6px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>LsrW's Go2 Links</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>

   <form method="get" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search" class="rounded">
   <img class="icon" src="images/search_Google.png"/>
    <center>
     <input name="q" maxlength="255" class="rounded-box"><input value="Search" type="submit" class="rounded-input">
   </form>
   <form method="get" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search" class="rounded">
   <img class="icon" src="images/search_Google.png"/>
    <center>
     <input name="q" maxlength="255" class="rounded-box"><input value="Search" type="submit" class="rounded-input">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Preview the issue here: [link](http://lsrw.co.uk/slider/) (http://lsrw.co.uk/slider/).

As you can see in the link (or if you preview the code, which may or may not display correctly anyway depending on the size of the window), the first search box works correctly with the image on the left, however the second does not.

Anyone have any ideas how you would fix this? (additional: I am open to suggestions of how to improve much of this, I'm relatively new to CSS).

Thanks,
- Luke

EDIT: This was pretty simple to fix, sorry for the dumb question- I had completely forgotten that I had added a  tag, closing that within the form fixed it completely.

Comment: Use left:6px rather than margin:10px 10px 10px 6px

Comment: Thanks Michael, however now the top alignment has gone.

Comment: Use top: also in conjunction

Comment: I would recommend using top:calc() or wrapping the slider in a position:relative and then keeping the .icon as a position:absolute

Comment: Thanks again Michael, I've been told not use the calc() tag because it isn't supported... would you agree with this? I fixed it by the way, I added: margin-top: 9px, left: 14px.

Comment: How far back are you trying to make your app cross browser supported?  If you're fine supporting IE10 (Windows 7) on desktop and Android 4.4+/iOS7, then you're fine using calc.  http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `<center>` tags are not closed. This leads to undefined behaviour.

Try to close both center tags:

```
        <form method="get" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search" class="rounded">
        <img class="icon" src="images/search_Google.png"/>
            <center>
                <input name="q" maxlength="255" class="rounded-box"><input value="Search" type="submit" class="rounded-input">
            </center>
        </form>
        <form method="get" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search" class="rounded">
        <img class="icon" src="images/search_Google.png"/>
            <center>
                <input name="q" maxlength="255" class="rounded-box"><input value="Search" type="submit" class="rounded-input">
            </center>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Fantastic... I had completely forgotten that I had even added that tag, your solution was perfect.